# Golang gorilla mux REST api is giving 405 error on using PUT and DELETE methods

Tags: rest, go, mux

Golang gorilla mux REST api is giving 405 error on using PUT and DELETE methods. But GET and POST methods are working fine.

I used postman to test my REST api server, GET and POST requests works fine but PUT and DELETE methods not working and giving **error 405**

```
...
...
func updateBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    for index, item := range books {
        if item.ID == params["id"]{
            books = append(books[:index], books[index+1:]...)
            var book Book
            _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&book)
            book.ID = params["id"]
            books = append(books, book)
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(books)
            return
        }
    }
}

func deleteBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    for index, item := range books {
        if item.ID == params["id"]{
            books = append(books[:index], books[index+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(books)
}



func main() {
    // INIT router
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // Mock data
    books = append(books, Book{
    ID: "1",
    Isbn: "43432",
    Title: "Book first",
    Author: &Author{
        FirstName: "Vishal",
        LastName: "Sharma",
    },
    })

    // Route handlers / Endpoints
    r.HandleFunc("/api/books", getbooks).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/books/{id}", getBook).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/books", createBook).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("api/books/{id}", updateBook).Methods("PUT")
    r.HandleFunc("api/books/{id}", deleteBook).Methods("DELETE")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r))
}
```

Comment: go version is 1.14

Comment: Aren't you missing the leading slashes in the endpoint pattern strings for those two methods? And if indeed that is the cause of the problem feel free to close/delete the question as the problem was caused by a typo.

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva, it was the typo. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, it was a typo.

```
r.HandleFunc("api/books/{1}", deleteBook).Methods("DELETE")
```

i am missing a / forward slash before the api/books/{1}

correct syntax is

```
r.HandleFunc("/api/books/{1}", deleteBook).Methods("DELETE")
```